# How to find the coordinates of the point on the line $2x + 6y - 2 = 0$ that is closest to the point $(0, -3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the point on the line $2x-6y+2=0$ which is closest to the point $(0,-3)$. I got $(-8,3)$ but my $x$ coordinate is wrong.

Comment: edit the post to show us your working and we can point out your mistake if any?

Comment: find the line perpendicular to $2x - 6y + 2 =0$ though the point $(0,-3), 6x + 2 (y+3) = 0$ and where does it intersect $2x - 6y + 2 =0$

Comment: 1x/3 +1/3= 3 I simplify and got x= -8 as my x-coordinate

Comment: $(-8,3)$ isn’t even on the given line.

Comment: @ArabelisMartinez How do you "simplify" ??

Answer (score 1):

Equation of given line: $3y=x+1\implies y=\frac13x+\frac13$

$\therefore$ Slope of given line = $\frac13$

$\implies$Slope of perpendicular line = $-3$

Equation of perpendicular line: $(y+3)=-3(x-0) \implies y=-3x-3$

Solve the two, and get $y = 0, x =-1$, i.e., $(-1,0)$

[image: perpendicular_lines]

Comment: My homework say that the first coordinate is incorrect

Comment: Is it possible that the answer mentioned in your homework is incorrect?

Comment: Is the second coordinate correct? If so, then the first coordinate must be correct (put value of second coordinate in the given equation to check).

Comment: This question is still giving me a headache, I don't get the right coordinates still

Comment: @ArabelisMartinez  These coordinates are indeed correct as the diagram I have added illustrates.

Answer (score 0):

You want to minimize the function that renders the distance from a generic point $\;\left(x,\,\frac13x+\frac13\right)\;$ on the line to $\;(0,-3)\;$ , so we get a function of $\;x\;$ :

$$f(x)=x^2+\left(\frac13x+\frac13+3\right)^2=x^2+\frac19(x^2+20x+100)=\frac{10}9x^2+\frac{20}9x+\frac{100}9\implies$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{20}9x+\frac{20}9\stackrel?=0\implies x=-1\,,\,\,etc.$$

We don't in fact need calculus here: the distance function squared (why is it enough to square the distance?) is an upward parabola who then has its *minimal* point at its vertx, which is given by

$$\left(-\frac b{2a}\,,\,\,-\frac{\Delta}{4a}\right)=\left(-\frac{\frac{20}9}{\frac{20}9}\,,\,\,-\frac{\frac{400}{81}-\frac{4000}{81}}{\frac{40}9}\right)$$

Comment: those points are incorrect according to my homework, I need to find the coordinates closest to (0,-3)

Comment: @ArabelisMartinez First, there are no points in my answer: there is **only** the abscissa of the wanted point: $\;x=-1\;$ . The ordinate $\;y\;$ of the wanted point is **for you** to find out. Second, the above is **correct**, so either you're looking at some incorrect answer or your homework is wrong.